# How can I replace a portion of the URL querystring in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

When I submit a form it appends the values to a querystring e.g. `page.html?q=value&z=value`, etc. I wish to remove a portion of the value that is appended to the querystring e.g. `page.html?q=value+OR+text%3Avalue&z=value`. The value I would like to replace is `+OR+text%3A(value)` so that the querystring looks like `page.html?q=value&z=value`. The code I have is as follows:

```
var testurl = document.URL;
var re = /[a-zA-Z\/:_\.]+\?q=[^&]+&[a-z]+\=[a-z]+/;
var decodeurl = unescape(testurl);
if(decodeurl.match(re)) {
  testurl = testurl.replace(/\+OR\+text:[a-zA-Z0-9]/,'');
  window.location.href = testurl;
```

It doesn't appear to be working as it seems to send the execution in some sort of endless loop.

Comment: If you want to redirect the page, try `window.location.assign(testurl)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try.

```
testurl = testurl.replace(\+OR\+.*\&,'\&');
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it still seems to result in an endless loop

Comment: What if you put a return false; after the window.location.href = testurl;

Comment: I'm not sure where you are running into the endless loop.  This stops further execution after the redirect.